# SharePoint online When date column has date in it or is TRUE update different column with preexisting selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, flow, powerapps-forms

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do in this specific circumstance.

I have a PowerApps form. In this form I have several fields but there are 2 that I'm trying to build a dependency on. A date column, friendly format and a choice column with only 1 option, the number 8.

What I would like to happen is, while the date column is empty the choice column should also stay empty but whenever a day is selected in the date column no matter what that date is the choice column will update to the choice of 8.

I know this can be done though a calculated column my dilemma is that I don't know the syntax to accomplish this. Additional I know this could also be done with a flow condition/switch but once again I don't know how to set that up correctly.

I could have case statements evaluate each day column I have and have a condition set up where if date == true update item but that would be 10 cases I need to build and 10 conditions. When a date column is empty does that necessarily mean it's false and full means true?

Is there a better/ more streamlined way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the calculated column to replace the choice column and use the formula [Ganesh Sanap](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69998/ganesh-sanap) provides. It would be the best solution.

Just FYI, if you are to use a flow, you can build an automated flow triggered on **When an item is created or modified** and use the expression **null** for empty column value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using calculated column very easily. use below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Column Name]), "", "8")
```